# Change gear on a shimano Schwinn Ranger, not sure what Allen key size to use?

Tags: shimano, repair, derailleur

I've tried an Allen key 7/64 but that didn't work and the others on my Allen key set but none seem to fit this shimano on a Schwinn Ranger.

One of the derailleur cogs broke in half.

Here is an image of a similar bike with the same Shimano drive train.

http://www.target.com/p/schwinn-mens-ranger-26-mountain-bike-red/-/A-15287654

Thank you!

Comment: What "plastic gears" are you talking about? Are you trying to remove the spoke guard on the wheel or the chain guard on the crank set?

Comment: @NateWengert it's not those. It's the gears that are on the Shimano mechanism themselves which hook into the bike chains on the back tire.

Comment: The cogs of the derailleur? What is the purpose of the change? If the derailleur is the issue you may just want to replace the whole thing. Or have it properly adjusted. I can't imagine that bike having overly high end parts.

Comment: One of the plastic cogs broke in half and to undo the cog there is an allen slot

Comment: Bike tools need to be metric sized. On Shimano components all screws are metric without exception. Using imperial sized wrenches will wreck the screw-heads.

Comment: Gotcha, yes you will need metric size allen wrenches, also if you're replacing it you will need a chain breaker to remove and reinstall the chain as well.

Comment: Modern bikes are metric.  Old bikes are imperial.  Carry the right tools for your need

Comment: Get yourself a set of metric Allen wrenches.

Comment: You need a metric allen wrench, or just get pocket bike tools, all metrics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_key

Comment: Thanks everyone picked up a "Park Tool" allen key wrench from my local bike shop for $4.99 and and the 3mm worked great! now to get the cog!

Answer (score 11):

The allen is almost certainly metric.  Both 2.5mm and 3mm are reasonably close to 7/64 inch.  3mm is a very common size on bikes.  If you are going to do any work on a bike you need metric allen wrenches.

Comment: What's not 3mm is *mostly* 5mm. And my pedals are 10mm.

Comment: Turned out to be 3mm. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

The rear der on that bike will cost you at most $20 US, but if you take what's left of the jockey wheel to your LBS (local bike shop) they should be able to hook you up with a new or used part for less than $5 us.

Comment: The question was about allen key size.